# Accessing Symbols In Wingdings Font

Tags: delphi, unicode, fonts

I am trying to print the symbols in the Wingdings font shown by Microsoft Word in the Symbol dialogue as symbols with character codes 129 to 138 ('1' to '10' in a circle') and 140 to 149 (white '1' to '10' in a black circle') but only those for '1', white '2', white'4' & white '5' appear correctly, the other symbols appearing in the printed list covering positions 1 to 20 are shown as a rectangle.

The following code works as intended using Delphi 5 and Rave Reports 4.0 (pre-Unicode) but fails as described using Delphi 10.1 and Rave 11.0.12;

```
 with Sender as TBaseReport do
 begin
      PushFont;
      SetFont('Wingdings', 10);
      FontCharSet := SYMBOL_CHARSET;
      if NoteNo < 11 then
         {0 - 10 = white (0) - (10).}
         PrintTab(char(128 + NoteNo))
      else
          if NoteNo < 21 then
             {11 - 20 = black (1) - (10).}
             PrintTab(char(128 + 1 + NoteNo))
          else
```

I assume now being in the Unicode era I am not stepping through the character set correctly, but due to ignorance on my part, I am not sure how I should change this code such that the correct symbols are accessed.

Comment: Some reading when migrating from pre-Unicode: [Delphi Unicode Migration for Mere Mortals: Stories and Advice from the Front Lines](https://www.embarcadero.com/images/dm/technical-papers/delphi-unicode-migration.pdf).

Comment: Thanks. I will study this with interest (and have added it to my favourites list in case I need to refer to it again).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know about report peculiarities, but this example works as intended in modern Delphi version (and shows empty rectangles if `Char` is used instead of `AnsiChar`)

```
var
  i: integer;
begin
  Canvas.Font.Name := 'Wingdings';
  Canvas.Font.Charset := SYMBOL_CHARSET;
  for i := 128 to 128 + 21 do
    Canvas.TextOut(0, 20 * (i - 128), AnsiChar(i));
```

Comment: Spot on! Thank you for such a rapid and precise solution to my problem. Works a treat. 8^) Learning all  the time...

Comment: I assume the code above should also have an implicit string cast warning so it should work fine on Western (CP-1252) code page but may not work on others. I would highly recommend to test it

Comment: I checked in 1251.  I don't know how `PrintTab` works.